# Python AND OR statements

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am parsing text with Python and I have this final code to write sentences, but it does not work well:

```
        opt = child.get('desc')
        extent = child.get('extent')
        if opt == 'es':
            opt = "ESP:"
        elif opt == "la":
            opt = "LAT:"
        elif opt == "en":
            opt = "ENG:"
if opt in ["es","la","en","ar","fr"] and extent == "begin":
    print time, opt+(" " + opt).join([c.encode('latin-1') for c in child.tail.split(' ')])
```

It works only with the OR statements, but when I add the `AND` statement (which I really need), nothing changes. Anyone please?

Comment: is `opt` a variable or `"opt"` string? It may be worth doing a check to see what `opt` and `extent` are

Comment: Should work. can you show how you get `opt` and `extend`?

Comment: Depending on what `opt` and `extent` is `and` and `or` could possibly  both have the same output

Comment: Yes, here some more extra code:
                       `opt = child.get('desc')
   extent = child.get('extent')

   if opt == 'es':
    opt = "ESP:"
   elif opt == "la":
    opt = "LAT:"
   elif opt == "en":
    opt = "ENG:"`

Comment: So it seems you've most likely just changed the value of `opt` to something that does not exist in the list of strings, which is why the `and` condition does not hold any longer, and hence does not execute.

Comment: If this statements structure does not work, I accept variations, but I need this kind of check. Firt, check the language (OR statements) and next, check if this language has the tag "begin"

Comment: @Sergi: print the value of `opt` and `extent`, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the output from the first line of code is `"ar"` or `"fr"` (or something else not in the `if-elif` conditions), you are over-writing the `opt` variable. Consider re-naming the 'new' `opt` to something else, like follows:

```
opt = child.get('desc')

extent = child.get('extent')

if opt == 'es':
    opt2 = "ESP:"
elif opt == "la":
    opt2 = "LAT:"
elif opt == "en":
    opt2 = "ENG:"

# Check variable values
print "opt: ", opt
print "opt2: ", opt2

if opt in ["es","la","en","ar","fr"] and extent == "begin":
    print time, opt2+(" " + opt2).join([c.encode('latin-1') for c in child.tail.split(' ')])
```

I am not sure what exactly you wish to achieve from the code, but the above will at least get your `if-else` condition met if the original `child.get('desc')` condition returns a string that exists in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your selection list in the first condition of your `if` statement is the problem.

If `opt` happens to be `es`, for example, then

```
if opt == 'es':
    opt = "ESP:"
```

will change that to  `ESP:`.

```
if opt in ["es","la","en","ar","fr"] and extent == "begin":
```

can then never be `True` (when you're using `and` instead of `or`).

If you change that line to something like

```
if opt in ["ESP:","LAT:","ENG:","ar","fr"] and extent == "begin":
```

it might work (if the code you've shown is all that's relevant to the problem).

Answer (score 1):

**AND**

To become condition True by **AND Operator**, required **True** result from the **all conditions**.

**OR**

To become condition True by **OR Operator**, required **True** result from the any **one condition**.

**E.g.**

```
In [1]: True and True
Out[1]: True

In [2]: True and False
Out[2]: False

In [3]: True or False
Out[3]: True
```

---

In your code, print following statements:

```
print "Debug 1: opt value", opt
print "Debug 2: extent value", extent
```

**Why use same variable name again??**

If value of `opt` is `es` then if condition `if opt == 'es':` is `True` and `opt` variable is again assign to vale `ESP:`. 
And in your final if statement you check `opt in ["es","la","en","ar","fr"]` , so which is always `False`.

```
    opt = child.get('desc')
#   ^^
    extent = child.get('extent')
    if opt == 'es':
        opt = "ESP:"
    #   ^^
    elif opt == "la":
        opt = "LAT:"
    elif opt == "en":
```

Answer (score 1):

When `opt` is one of these: `"es", "la", "en"`
then the value of `opt` is changed, and this:
`if opt in ["es","la","en","ar","fr"] and extent == "begin":`
won't pass, because `opt` is wrong.

I guess `extent` is equal `"begin"`, so if u swap `and` with `or` it will pass, as one of the statements is correct. Try to remove this big `if/elif/elif` and try to run it again with `and`. It should pass.

Answer (score 0):

This is an operator precedence problem. You expect the code to work as:

```
if (opt in ["es","la","en","ar","fr"]) and (extent == "begin"):
    print time, opt+(" " + opt).join([c.encode('latin-1') for c in child.tail.split(' ')])
```

But it works as

```
if opt in (["es","la","en","ar","fr"] and extent == "begin"):
    print time, opt+(" " + opt).join([c.encode('latin-1') for c in child.tail.split(' ')])
```

which evaluates to different values than you expect.

Try the parentheses in the first code piece.